# How to fetch the Email of a user in a teams channel with a teams bot using SDK 4?

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am developing a chat bot for teams chat and channels and for one of my functions, i need the email of the user the bot is chatting to.
I have successfully implemented this for teams chat in the following manner.

```
var uid = await TeamsInfo.getMember(
            context,
            context.activity.from.id
        );
var emailid = uid.userPrincipalName;
```

But for the teams channel i want the same but i want to fetch this from the message the user sends in the channel to identify the user and their email and send it to the backend.
So, how would i be able to fetch the email by the message that user sends in the teams channel?

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the email of a user who sends a message in a Teams channel, you can use the TeamsInfo.getMember() method in a similar way as you did for the Teams chat. The only difference is that you need to use the from.id property of the activity object that represents the message sent by the user in the channel.
Here is how you can do it:

```
var userId = context.activity.from.id;
var user = await TeamsInfo.getMember(context, userId);
var email = user.userPrincipalName;
```

In this code:
context.activity.from.id gives you the ID of the user who sent the message in the channel.
TeamsInfo.getMember(context, userId) fetches the details of the user with the given ID.
user.userPrincipalName gives you the email of the user.
Please note that the bot must have the necessary permissions to fetch user details. Also, the userPrincipalName property represents the email of the user only if the email is used as the user principal name in your organization.

Comment: Thanks , i will have to try it out and get back to you! 
Do you know how to add a bot created using teams bot toolkit to a teams channel?

Comment: Yes, First, ensure that your bot is uploaded and published to the Teams store or your organization's app catalog. If you haven't done this yet, you can follow the guide on how to upload your app in a team.
Once your bot is available in the Teams store or your organization's app catalog, you can add it to a Teams channel. Here are the steps:
On the Teams desktop client, go to the channel where you want to add the bot.
Click on the More icon on the left side of Teams.
Search for your bot in the search bar.
Click on your bot to add it to the channel.

Comment: so, i use the teams bot toolkit and host the bot locally to build it up, is there any way i can add the bot to a channel when it is hosted locally?

Comment: you can add your locally hosted bot to a channel in Teams.
This can be achieved using a tunneling service like ngrok.
Download and install ngrok from https://ngrok.com/download. Add ngrok to your path.
Start the tunneling service by running the following command in your terminal:
ngrok http <port> --host-header=localhost:<port>
Replace <port> with the port number your bot is running on.
Use the https endpoint provided by ngrok in your app manifest.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema
Create an app package and upload it to Teams.